# How to stop VS Code from omitting parentheses after auto-formatting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autoformatting

I am using ReactJs and as recommended, I put JSX code inside parentheses after return statement like this:

```
 return (
<div>...</div>
)
```

However when I saved it, it automatically became like this:

```
return <div>...</div>
```

I think it's because of some auto-formatting extension (I'm using Prettier).
Could you guys please show me the way to keep the parentheses without disabling Prettier or any other autoformat extension? Thank you.

Comment: Prettier is fairly opinionated about its formatting. There are some configuration options, but I don't think this is one of them https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Comment: Wich version of prettier are you using? The 2.0 solved a lot of this issues https://prettier.io/blog/2020/03/21/2.0.0.html

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but I found the answer for someone in the future.

i had to uninstall prettier and go to settings.json and erase the lines

"prettier.arrowParens": "avoid"
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",